# ApiPlatform\Core\DataPersister\ContextAwareDataPersisterInterface service does not exists

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, api-platform.com

Hey Im trying API Platform with Symfony 6.0 (and PHP 8)

Everything was going alright until I needed to make a DataPersister so I can encrypt the user password before saving it

I literally copied the example in the docs (here https://api-platform.com/docs/core/data-persisters/#decorating-the-built-in-data-persisters) since my entity is actually called User:

```
<?php

namespace App\DataPersister;

use ApiPlatform\Core\DataPersister\ContextAwareDataPersisterInterface;
use App\Entity\User;

final class UserDataPersister implements ContextAwareDataPersisterInterface
{
    private $decorated;

    public function __construct(ContextAwareDataPersisterInterface $decorated)
    {
        $this->decorated = $decorated;

    }

    public function supports($data, array $context = []): bool
    {
        return $this->decorated->supports($data, $context);
    }

    public function persist($data, array $context = [])
    {
        $result = $this->decorated->persist($data, $context);

        return $result;
    }

    public function remove($data, array $context = [])
    {
        return $this->decorated->remove($data, $context);
    }
}
```

I just removed the mailer parts cause what Im trying to do has nothing to do with that. Other than that, it is exactly equal to the example

But it wont work. I get this error when I try to persist:

```
Cannot autowire service "App\DataPersister\UserDataPersister": argument "$decorated" of method "__construct()" references interface "ApiPlatform\Core\DataPersister\ContextAwareDataPersisterInterface" but no such service exists. Try changing the type-hint to "ApiPlatform\Core\DataPersister\DataPersisterInterface" instead.
```

I tried doing what the error suggests but it seems to throw the framework in some endless loop or something cause I get a memory error. And in any case, I need a ContextAwareDataPersisterInterface

Am I doing something wrong or missing something here? Or this a bug? The docs says:
"If service autowiring and autoconfiguration are enabled (they are by default), you are done!"

They are both enabled in services.yaml:

```
# This file is the entry point to configure your own services.
# Files in the packages/ subdirectory configure your dependencies.

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices.html#use-parameters-for-application-configuration
parameters:

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'

    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones
```

Comment: Thanks for this question! It helped my figure out that Data Persisters are no longer called that in API Platform 3. Now they're known as "State Processors": https://api-platform.com/docs/main/core/state-processors/.

Answer (score 3):

I works if I explicity define the service in services.yaml:

```
App\DataPersister\UserDataPersister:
    bind:
        $decorated: '@api_platform.doctrine.orm.data_persister'
```

edit: sorry, the documentation actually says we have to do that, I missed it. My bad.

Problem solved